# PHP MYSQL display table with action row clickable to open specific file

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am having this type of problem. I have a table displayed on my webpage. Wherein I have an Action column. I am trying to make my (a href) code open different files depending on what was indicated on my table whether it is pdf or an excel file.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","annualdb");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM aviation_report");

    echo "<head><style>
    table {
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    </style></head>";
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Agency</th>
    <th>FileName</th>
    <th>FileType</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['agency'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['filetype'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='sample.pdf'>OPEN FILE</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Everytime I clicked the OPEN FILE, it always show the same pdf file.

Comment: Its because you have `<a href='sample.pdf'>` for all rows.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem. I've been trying jquery for this. but always fail to output different results.

Comment: You would have something like : `<a href='" . $row['filename'] . "'>`

Comment: should I put that inside the <td> tag too?

Comment: Added an answer

Comment: yes, it's just the same. The point is to replace the hard-coded filename with one which comes dynamically from your data. Same way you output the other fields from $row. You just have to put it into the correct place in the HTML.

Comment: Isn't it the same? BTW, my pdf and excel files are in my local file system. Not on a database

Comment: I've been putting it everywhere in the HTML. But it still shows the same result

Comment: No but the file _name_ is in your database, isn't it. All you're doing is generating a _link_ to the file by printing the filename inside the "href" attribute of the link. As well as that, the actual file itself must be accessible via a HTTP request to your webserver otherwise the link won't work when it's clicked on. If your webserver is also on localhost and your files are in the same folder as your PHP script then the link (as per Anurag's answer) should work.

Comment: I tried Anurag's answer, and I got an Object not found error

Comment: That sounds like a 404 error. Like I said, the link must point to where the files are actually located on your webserver. It's not magic, they have to be located in the correct place (same as PHP scripts do). If they're not there, then you need put them there. You can of course put them in a subdirectory and add that to the path shown in the href. But they have to be accessible by HTTP request to the server. It cannot fetch them from your local filesystem - the browser does not have access the filesystem of the machine where it is running (and rightly so, for security reasons).

Comment: I am using xampp for this, and I store my files on a folder named "datartrvr" inside the htdocs folder. I would like to know if this is the correct place to put my files and where should it be located.

Comment: The only requirement is it needs to be somewhere under the root folder of your website, that's all. So wherever your .php file is stored, they need to be in that folder, or in a subfolder under it. How precisely you decide to organise it is up to you - to make it neat and tidy you could add a "/docs" folder under the main folder, for instance. And then the href would be `href='docs/" . $row['filename'] . "'` so that it generates the correct URL relative to the site's root. Your webserver basically can access a subset of the server's filesystem, from the defined site root downwards.

Comment: P.S. When you click the link, you'll be able to see in the browser bar what the final URL it generates is, so if you used a subfolder and it's not getting you to the right folder when you click, you can play with it quite easily until it's right. Show us a diagram of the folder structure if you're still unsure.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. contrary to what you just said. It worked like magic. haha My problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have this code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['agency'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['filetype'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='" . $row['filename'] . "'>OPEN FILE</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. it is clearly the right answer. but my filename is just a string, not a blob. I store all my files in my local computer, and wanting to retrieve it by clicking the OPEN FILE button

Comment: "my filename is just a string" ...yes and that's fine. Because a hyperlink is just some text, which just points the browser to where it can go and find the file. It does not, and cannot, contain the file data. All it does is triggers the browser to make another HTTP request to the server, in order to retrieve the file. The files must be accessible via a HTTP request to the server when the link is clicked. You cannot embed the file data within your webpage directly.

Comment: You might want to move your files to a folder in the server root (localhost), and store the file path as well in your db. Then you would have something like: `$row['filepath'] = '/path/to/mysample.pdf'` and `<a href='" . $row['filepath'] . "'>`